# building a pixel art maker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a small pixel art maker grid but I have a small issue after I create a table I wanna clear the table before submitting a form

---

this is my code.

the clearTable function isn't working well.

when I submit the form first it should generate a table data than when I submit again it should first delete the table data and then regenerate it all over again

```js
// Select color input
const clrInput = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
// Select size input
const sizePicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");
// pixelCanvas table
const pixelCanvas = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');

// When size is submitted by the user, call makeGrid()
sizePicker.addEventListener("submit", makeGrid);
// continuous changing
clrInput.addEventListener('change', onChangeColor);

function makeGrid(event) {
  if (pixelCanvas.childElementCount > 0) {
        clearTable();
  }
  // Your code goes here!
  //prevent default submitting
  event.preventDefault();
  // take the value of the input
  const row = this.elements.height.value;
  const column = this.elements.width.value;
  // pass row and column value to createTable function
  createTable(row, column);
}

function createTable(numberRow, numberColumn) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberRow; i++) {
        const tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
        for (let j = 0; j < numberColumn; j++) {
          const tableData = document.createElement('td');
          tableData.style.backgroundColor = clrInput.value;
          tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
        }
        pixelCanvas.appendChild(tableRow);
  }
}

function clearTable() {
    for (let i = 0; i < pixelCanvas.childElementCount; i++) {
        pixelCanvas.children[i].remove();
    }
}

function onChangeColor(event) {
  if (pixelCanvas.childElementCount !== 0) {
    const color = event.target.value;
    for (let r = 0; r < pixelCanvas.childElementCount; r++) {
        for (let c = 0; c < pixelCanvas.children[r].childElementCount; c++) {
            pixelCanvas.children[r].children[c].style.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Monoton;
  font-size: 70px;
  margin: 0.2em;
}

h2 {
  margin: 1em 0 0.25em;
}

h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
  height: 20px;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 6em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

    <h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1"> Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="inputWidth" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit" id='btn'>
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2 id='afterheading'>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

    <script src="designs.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your `clearTable` function doesn't work:
After each iteration of the loop, `pixelCanvas.childElementCount` decreases by one due to a child being removed. So your `i` and `pixelCanvas.childElementCount` meet in the middle and only about half the children get removed.

If you want to remove children that way, a way to do it is to iterate backwards.

```
for (let i = pixelCanvas.childElementCount; i > 0; i--) {
  pixelCanvas.children[i-1].remove();
}
```

Or do something easier like clearing the innerHTML.

```
pixelCanvas.innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through all the child elements it might be easier to just clear them all using `innerHTML`:

```
function clearTable() {
    pixelCanvas.innerHTML = '';
}
```

It's going to do pretty much the same thing and would most likely be more efficient than looping through all the elements.